# Can I use a lambda button command in a method?

Tags: python, class, methods, lambda, tkinter

I have been coding in python for a quite a short time and so do not fully understand the logic of the language especially when using Tkinter. I am currently working on the navigation system of the system I am developing specifically at the log in page. Below is my code in question:

```
class Application(Tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = Tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (createLogin, createHome, createViewer, createAnalyse):

            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(createLogin)

    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

    def connectToDataBase(self):
        cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb,      *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\Users\Public\dbsDetectorBookingSystem.accdb')
        cursor = cnxn.cursor()

        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM tblUsers")
        userRows = cursor.fetchall

        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM tblRuns")
        runsRows = cursor.fetchall



class createLogin(Tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        Tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)

        topFrame= Tk.Frame(self)
        topFrame.pack(side="top")

        leftFrame = Tk.Frame(topFrame)
        leftFrame.pack(side="left")

        nameLabel = Tk.Label(leftFrame, text = "Username")
        nameLabel.pack(side="top", padx = 5, pady = 10)

        passwordLabel = Tk.Label(leftFrame, text = "Password")
        passwordLabel.pack(side="top", padx = 5, pady = 10)

        rightFrame = Tk.Frame(topFrame)
        rightFrame.pack(side="left")

        nameText = Tk.Text(rightFrame, height=1, width = 30)
        nameText.pack(side="top", padx = 5, pady = 10)

        passwordText = Tk.Text(rightFrame, height=1, width = 30)
        passwordText.pack(side="top", padx = 5, pady = 10)

        botFrame = Tk.Frame(self)
        botFrame.pack(side="top")

        Login = Tk.Button(botFrame, text="Login")
        Login["command"] = lambda: self.checkLogin()
        Login.pack(side="left", padx = 5, pady = 10)
```

What I would like to do is have the login button call a method which can validate the text boxes with username and password in from the read in database, if they are correct then the 'show_frame' method should be called. I can implement the validation however whenever I create a method to try and call the 'show_frame' I have to create a new instance of the application class which is far from desirable, what I really want to do is trigger that method, passing 'createHome' in the current instance of the Application class.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated sorry for being such a novice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `createLogin` class already has a reference to the main application, so I don't understand why you think you have to "create a new instance of the application class".

I think all you need to do is save the instance of `controller` and use it to call the `show_frame` method.

```
class createLogin(Tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        Tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        self.controller = controller
        ...
        Login = Tk.Button(botFrame, text="Login", command=self.checkLogin)
        ...
    def checkLogin(self):
        ...
        if correct_password:
            self.controller.show_frame(createHome)
```

Comment: Thanks that works, like I say I am new to the language (and GUI programming in general), other things I found online about using a method from another class just said to create a new instance of the class which is where that idea came from. You've been very helpful.